# How to do script calculation on Facet value?

Tags: elasticsearch, facet

I want to implement script in to my app which is using Elasticsearch 0.19.  I could find only the term Facet be applied with script on its "field term".  Is it possible to apply script over the "field value"?

I could only find examples applying script on the "field term" like below:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {  }
    },
    "facets" : {
        "tag" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "tag",
                "size" : 10,
                "script" : "term + 'aaa'"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!
Manoj

Answer (score 0):

An optimal way to achieve this, would be to index the field [the second time](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/multi-field-type.html) as not_analyzed fields, and use this "untouched" version in facet. This way your terms will be equal to field values. Alternatively, if your index is not very large and you field is stored, you can try using [script_field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/terms-facet.html).

Comment: Hmm, I think I am not clear with the requirement. This is what it, I believe Facet would only return the count of the 'term' as 'value'. I too need the same facet 'count' for a script operation. Does your solution too taking me to the same solution. Hope I didn't miss anything now

Comment: Not sure I am following. Could you add an example that would demonstrate your requirement?